# Using garbage values to generate random or Pseudo-random numbers

Tags: c, garbage-collection

I come across this idea of using garbage values to generate random numbers. In C the variable that is not initialised is given a garbage value(but when I try it in my geany it gives a 0). So if want to take a random number from 50-60. Can I take the modulus of garbage values and then add them to the initial limit of the random number. But uninitialised variable returns zero instead of garbage value as in this post @ [How garbage values are assigned to variables in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326611/how-garbage-values-are-assigned-to-variables-in-c)

```
int i;
int LowerLimit=50;
int UpperLimit=60;
int RandomNumber = i%(UpperLimit-LowerLimit) + LowerLimit;
```

Also what if we use a hundred uninitialised variables to use a combination of them to generate a random variable.

Comment: If you really want to do this, use the uninitialized variable to seed a pseudo-random number generator. Better, don't use such variables.

Comment: Why are you unhappy calling 0 a garbage value?

Comment: How can 0 be garbage value? @glglgl

Comment: @xtreak - What does garbage mean for you ? This `%&&%%^$$%#$#$((*&(*&*(&`?

Comment: By garbage it means the data which was there previously - it could be anything. `0`, `111111`,`(*&(`, `Hello World`, `╪`,etc. Just anything.

Answer (score 7):

Using uninitialized variables as random values is a very bad idea in practice. Using uninitialized values is [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so everything could happen, but in practice a local uninitialized variable may hold some well repeatable value. Some compilers are clever enough, when optimizing, to remove some uses of uninitialized values (or on the contrary to set that value as a constant). This is conforming to C or C++ standards.

Recent [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard has defined a quite extensive API for random numbers. See the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) C++11 standard header.

I mean that if you print some uninitialized value, you may get *in practice* always the same value when running the same program several times on the same machine, and I don't call that a random behavior. Of course the behavior is *implementation specific* (and will vary from one system to the next; it is dependent on the operating-system, compiler, optimization flags, and user configuration or environment, etc...).

I suggest using some [pseudo-random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_generator) (e.g. see [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) or [lrand48(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lrand48.3.html)...) and seeding it with some random input. On Linux you could read some few bytes from `/dev/urandom` (read carefully [urandom(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/urandom.4.html) ...) or combine the current time with the current pid (see [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) and [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html)) to obtain a seed.

And random numbers does not mean much, and randomness is difficult to define precisely in practice (ask a mathematician, specialist in probabilities).

<sup>Random numbers is really a difficult subject. You can spend your entire life on it, and get a PhD....</sup>

For debugging purposes you may want to have a reproducible stream of pseudo-random numbers. To get that, use a well defined seed.

If your problem depends crucially on having a really random and unpredictable stream of numbers (e.g. if you are coding a poker web site), it is worth spending a few hundred euros (or dollars) buying some hardware random device.

Comment: Well how about using the number generated into pi that has no repetitive sequence? @Basile

Comment: Computing digits (or bits) of pi is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

An uninitialized variable is a variable that is declared but is not set to a definite known value before it is used. It will have some value, but not a predictable one. Which means that it can have `100` stored in the variable even if you generate a random number a 1000 times and maybe on the 1001th time you get some other number. This is not a good idea. When something is undefined we can just not have any clue what will happen, and generating random numbers needs a proper algorithm, its not something a programmer is clueless about.

This is non-standard. I believe SO expects standard coding.

Comment: But uninitialised values get zero in my code is it compiler dependent? I mean using a 100 different uninitialised variables to get such numbers in a function like a one that adds them all to give a number that is random and hence using modulus.

Comment: `is it compiler dependent?` - No it is standard dependent. Also it maybe that variable is getting placed in the same exact memory location in each run. Now i say this for variables which are of `auto` storage class. Are you sure your variable is not static or global? If not then its a coincidence which i talked about in my answer.

Comment: @xtreak No, it depends on where you put the variable. And, for the case of auto variables (aka local ones), it depends on the history of function calls and stack usage. And in the case of `malloc()`, it depends on the history of heap usage.

Comment: `it depends on the history of heap usage` - Bang on! Just what my point was.

Comment: As of C 2011, an uninitialized object cannot be expected to have some value, even an unspecified value. If you use an automatic object that has not had its address taken, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, per C 2011 6.3.2.1 2. (This supports certain HP hardware with special flags that indicate a register is uninitialized, but optimizers in other C implementations may take advantage of it too,)