# What is the origin of garbage value?

Tags: c

When we define a variable, and do not initialize it, the block of memory allocated to the variable still contains a value from previous programs, known as garbage value. But suppose, in a hypothetical case, a block of unused memory is present in the system, and when I declare and define a variable, that block of memory is allocated to the variable. If I do not initialize the variable, and try to print the value of the variable, the system doesn't have any garbage value to print. What will be the result? What will the system do?

Comment: *If I do not initialize the variable, and try to print it, it doesn't has any garbage value to print. What will it do?* .. Huh? Who is "It"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How garbage values are assigned to variables in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326611/how-garbage-values-are-assigned-to-variables-in-c)

Comment: Itanium, aka IA64, has NaT bits on its registers. That is "Not A Thing." This is used for speculative execution and also for debugging, and if you use one of those NaT values, your program crashes.

Comment: @ZanLynx In C terminology that is a trap representation. Which I touched on briefly.

Comment: Please provide a reference to the standard defining "garbage value". An uninitialised automatic variable with the address not taken, but read invokes undefined behaviour. That's not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we define a variable, and do not initialize it, the block of memory allocated to the variable still contains a value from previous programs, known as garbage value.
>
> If I do not initialize the variable, and try to print it, it doesn't have any garbage value to print.

C does not specify these behaviors.  There is no specified *garbage value*.

If code attempts to print (or use) the value of an uninitialized object, the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Anything may happen: a trap error occurs, the value is [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29), code dies, *anything*.

There is a special case if the uninitialized object is an `unsigned char` in that a value will be there of indeterminate value, just something in the range [`0...UCHAR_MAX`], but no UB.  This is the closest to *garbage value* C specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it isn't defined how an implementation behaves precisely when an uninitialised read is made, by the C standard. Merely that the value is not defined. The system may use whatever method it wishes to choose the value. Or it is even possible it is a trap representation and will crash the program I believe.

However on most real modern OSes. The data in reality is fresh pages that get mapped into the programs address space. For security reasons most kernels actually explicitly ensure these are zeroed out to avoid software spying on data from previous programs which were run and got left in memory.

However some OSes as you say will just leave this data in, meaning the page is either fresh and usually zeroed out or contains arbitrary data from previous programs (or even potentially arbitrary data defined by how the memory starts up, but at least with DRAM, that is generally in a zeroed state).

Comment: Wrong premise: It very well is defined by the standard what reading an uninitialised or not previously written to variable means!

Comment: @Olaf I think you misunderstand what I meant. I am saying the standard most certainly does not define precisely what an implementation will do when such a read is made. If you can show me differently and in fact implementations must take some specific course of action please send me a quote or at least a paragraph I can look to.

Comment: @Olaf I reworded it it case my wording is what you dislike.

Comment: Read my comment carefully again. The standard is very celar about what this means: UB. No need to further research; the implementation can do whatever it want, including formatting your mass storage. Your answer is not correct. Additionally you mix abstraction layers.

Comment: @olaf How can you possibly say that the standard defines what the implementation does then you also explicitly say the standard doesn't define it "UB" literally means undefined behaviour, meaning the standard doesn't define it... You seem to be arguing the standard defines it by not defining it... I really don't understand the issue

Comment: @olaf additionally mixing abstraction layers is intentional. I was starting it isn't defined then saying what some implementations choose to do as it isn't defined. It isn't unreasonable to want to know some particular implementarion defines a behaviour which the standard doesn't define. An implementation can define the behaviour of any situation it likes which is UB in the standard...

Comment: "An implementation can define the behaviour of any situation ..." - No implementation defines this behaviour - for good reasons! Feel free to provide a reference to any implementation defining how it handles this (other than invoking UB).

Comment: @Olaf I dont have time right now to research in detail, but take a look at LLVM with Address Sanitizer enabled. I beleive it has an option which defines uninitialized reads to always crash the program and produce a trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more of hardware perspective.

What is a memory? An example of memory: is made up of transistors and capacitors. A transistor and capacitor make a memory bit. A bit is either of value 0 or 1, a hypothetical scenario of non-existance of this bit value does not exist ;) as it has to hold either 0 or 1 and nothing else. If you think there is "nothing" in bit value, that means the hardware(transistor/capacitor) you are imagining is not working.

A bunch of bits makes a word or byte. A bunch of bytes holds an integer/ float or whatever variable you define. So even without initializing the variable, it contains 0's and 1's in each of the memory cells. When you access this - it's called garbage.

Comment: "Memory is made up of transistors and capacitors" - could be as well made of magnetic bubbles, coins, magneto-rsistive elements, holes or light flashes - and sometimes is. That's completely irrelevant and does not really answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, @Olaf, updated the answer. But I think it's still relevant to what OP has asked

Answer (score -1):

> But suppose, in a hypothetical case, a block of unused memory is present in the system, and when I declare and define a variable, that block of memory is allocated to the variable. If I do not initialize the variable, and try to print it, it doesn't has any garbage value to print. What will it do?

Any given memory location has *some* value, no matter how it got there. The "garbage" value doesn't have to come from a program that ran in that space previously, it could just be the initial state of the memory location when the system starts up. The reason it's "garbage" is that you don't know what it is -- you didn't put it there, you don't have any idea how it got there, and you don't really care.