# C++ Visual Studio: Uninitialized local variable 'response' used

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I try to run my code, i get the error C4700, or Uninitialized local variable 'response' used. I am a total beginner at coding c++ and I don't understand what this means. I've tried adding

```
char* response = "yes" "no"
```

and it ran, but when I enter yes or no I get the error Unhandled exception at 0x01222C4B in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0122EAB4. I also have no idea what this means.

Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){


int a, b, sum;

cout << "Hey, wanna play a game?" << endl;

char* response;
cin >> response;

if (response == "no"){

    cout << "Too bad!" << endl;
}
else if (response == "yes"){

    cout << "Ok, here we go!" << endl;
}
```

If you do decide to give a solution, please try to explain it a little bit so I can understand and learn.

Thanks.

Comment: Is not recommend to use `char*` when you using `cin`. Is there any reason you use `char*` instead of `string` ?

Comment: No, I just didn't know which to use at the right time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 
`char *response`
with `string response`

`char *` is a pointer with [garbage value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326611/how-garbage-values-are-assigned-to-variables-in-c) since it isn't initialized with some valid memory. 
When you do `cin >> response` it tries to write to the location pointed by the garbage value. This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and hence the access violation.

When you use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) instead, it makes sure that necessary space and valid memory is available. It would allocate memory as required. Details of how this happens would be beyond the scope of this answer. But if you are curious, this invokes the `operator >>` overload for `std::string`. The operator would dynamically allocate required memory.

Comment: It worked. I was experimenting and I noticed that if I used char response and y and n it would work perfectly. I see what I did wrong now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's because `char` is not a pointer type and hence would have some space allocated for it on stack. `cin >> response` would not try to write at the memory location pointed by `response` but would rather write at the memory allocated for the `char`