# How to receive standard input from keyboad properly in a child process?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, c

I'm running the following C program on Linux.

**Program**

```
// program.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    if (fork() == 0) { // child process
        int a, b;
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Expected behavior**

```
$ ./program
1 2
1 + 2 = 3
```

**Actual behavior**

```
$ ./program
$ 1222245440 + 32764 = 1222278204
```

When I run the program in the terminal, it produces strange output like `1222245440 + 32764 = 1222278204` and doesn't wait for me to type. Is there a method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the problem is that the standard input and output streams of the child process are not attached to the terminal. Instead, the streams of parent process are attached.

The parent process doesn't wait for the child and returns immediately. The orphaned child cannot read from the terminal, the "strange output" is from [garbage values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15326611/10765659) of `a` and `b`. See what `scanf` returns, run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    int wstatus;
    if (fork() == 0) { // child process
        int a, b, n;
        n=scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("(%d returned) %d + %d = %d\n", n, a, b, a + b);
    }
//    wait(&wstatus);
    return 0;
}
```

You will most likely get something like `(-1 returned) 1222245440 + 32764 = 1222278204`. Then uncomment `wait` and try again.