# couple of small questions of my first program

Tags: c

so I am new at c and I have couple of questions from my first program. I wrote a program that return the sum the difference the product the divide and the reminder of two numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a, b, c, d, f, h, g;
  c = a + b;
  d = a - b;
  f = a * b;
  h = a / b;
  g = a % b;

  printf("Enter two numbers:");
  scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b);
  printf("%d\n",c);
  printf("%d\n",d);
  printf("%d\n",f);
  if (b != 0 ) {
  printf("%d\n",h);
  printf("%d\n",g);
  }
}
```

so for some reason the compiler show the first sentence (enter two numbers) and then do nothing, secondly I don't know what is & in

```
scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b);
```

if I didn't write it the compiler will tell me that the argument is int* but the argument has type int. What is Int* ?

also I noticed that if I didn't but scanf the compiler will show still number, how is that ?

```
32766
-32766
0
0
0
```

Comment: `&a` means "location of a". You are telling `scanf` where `a` can be found so that it can write to `a`.  Also, `int*` is said "pointer to int". If a variable is of type `int*`, it can hold the location to an `int`. So, basically, you can write `int* pointsToA = &a;`, then use that `pointsToA` to indirectly modify the contents of `a`.

Comment: regarding: `c = a + b;
  d = a - b;
  f = a * b;
  h = a / b;
  g = a % b;`  since variable `a` and variable `b` have not been initialized (your compiler should have told you about this problem)  Therefore, there are lots of undefined behavior in the posted program.  strongly suggest moving those statements to after the call to `scanf()`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b);` 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: The `scanf()` family of functions return the number of successful 'input format specifiers'.  In the current statement, any returned value other than 2 indicates an error occurred.  2) do NOT place a '\n' at the end of the format string

Comment: These values in your output: `32766
-32766`  are the trash that is on the stack where the variables `a` and `b` located

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this](https://boredzo.org/pointers/) about *Pointers* (C is a `Pointer Language`).

`&` means the *address* of your datatype in your *storage*

`*` means the *value* of your datatype in your *storage*

A great example for this is this piece of code:

```
double x, *y;
x = 5.0;
y = &x;
*y = -3.0;
```

Now `x` has the value `-3.0`, because `y` is the *adress* of `x` and `*y` changes the value of the *adress* of `x`.

Comment: Understanding how pointers work is fundamental to understanding how to program in C. I strongly suggest you read about them as suggested in this answer, and then play with pointers until you are confident in your understanding of their usage.

Comment: regarding: `double x, y;`  and `y = &x;`  the declaration of `y` should be: `*y`  because it will contain a pointer-to-double not a double

Answer (score 1):

A program will perform tasks in the order in which they are written.

You simply need to ask for the values of a and b before performing calculations using them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a, b, c, d, f, h, g;

  printf("Enter two numbers:");
  scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b);

  c = a + b;
  d = a - b;
  f = a * b;
  h = a / b;
  g = a % b;

  printf("%d\n",c);
  printf("%d\n",d);
  printf("%d\n",f);
  if (b != 0 ) {
  printf("%d\n",h);
  printf("%d\n",g);
  }
}
```

To answer your other question, & and * are dealing with pointers - the location of the variable in memory.  It took me a lot of time and practise before I felt comfortable with the concept, so don't be surprised if you struggle with it at first - stick with it - you'll get there.

Basically

```
int n;
```

creates an integer variable in memory with n being it's reference name.
You can find the memory address at which that integer is stored using **&n**.

```
int *n;
```

creates a pointer to a memory location, with the pointer name being n.  It does not create an integer variable.

So, you can:

```
int a;
int *p;

p=&a; /* Set pointer to be the address of the variable a in memory */

a = 5;  /* Set a value for a */

printf("a = %d\n", a);   /* show a */
printf("a = %d\n", *p);  /* Show the contents at address p */

printf("p = %p\n", p);   /* show p */
printf("p = %p\n", &a);  /* show the memory address where a is stored */
```

Comment: H should be float and you should cast one of the operator of the division

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia `int h` is fine here to show integer division.  If a floating point quotient was desired, using `double` math and no cast is better. `double H = 1.0 * a / b;`.  Casting tends to hides problems and `double` is the _default_ FP type of C.

Comment: it this: `if (b != 0 ) {` is true, then this:  `h = a / b;` will result in a program crash due to dividing by 0

Answer (score 0):

so for some reason the compiler show the first sentence (enter two numbers) and then do nothing :

printf(...) : prints the message to your screen.

scanf(...) : will stop the program and wait for your input.which means you 
     should enter the value of a and b respectively.

& : it mean the address of the variable a or b, because your program will store data in memory that means you need to specify the address in memory where those values of a and b are gonna be stored.
if you don't use & it will generate this error : " the argument is int* but the argument has type int". its because '*a' is the value of the variable and it's of type int but '&a' is the address of the variable and it's of type int* (more about it when you get to pointers in c you can check this [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)). what you need to know is that scanf() will take &a not a.

and why you get those random values if you dont use scanf(...) ?
they are called garbage values more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326611/how-garbage-values-are-assigned-to-variables-in-c)