# Unable to add array values entered by the user

Tags: c++

Hello I'm working on an assignment for my C++ class and have ran into an issue. The instructions are;
Create a integer type two-dimensional array of 4 rows and 3 columns

Populate the two-dimensional array with values entered by the user, use a function for this, call this function userInputValues().

Print the array in a spreadsheet format, also print the sum of the values of each row. The out put must be:

```
                                             Row Totals
           value01   value02   value03         Sum01
           value04   value05   value06         Sum02
           value07   value08   value09         Sum03 
           value10   value11   value12         Sum04
```

The column's values and Sums must be right justified. Use the sew() function.

Use a function to print the values. Call this function printValues().

Must use loops to enter values, traverse the array, calculate sum, and print the values in the array.

---

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int const ROWS = 4;
int const COLUMNS = 3;

void userInputValue(int myArray[ROWS][COLUMNS]);
void printValues(const int myArray[ROWS][COLUMNS]);

int main()
{
int myArray[ROWS][COLUMNS];

userInputValue(myArray);
printValues(myArray);
return 0;

} 

void userInputValue(int myArray[ROWS][COLUMNS])
{
int index = 0;

cout << "Enter 12 numbers" << endl;

for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row)
{
for(int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; ++column)
 {
   cout << ++index << ". Enter a number: ";
   cin >> myArray[row][column];
   
  }
 }
} // End of method userInputValue

void printValues(const int myArray[ROWS][COLUMNS])
{

  cout << right << setw(20) << "Row Totals" << endl; 

  for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
 {
    int sum;  

    for (int column = 0; column < COLUMNS; ++column)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << myArray[row][column]; 

        sum = sum + myArray[row][column]; 
    }

    cout << setw(6) << sum<<'\n';  

  }
} // End of printValues
```

When I run the code I get,
Row Totals
10  2  3-434904305
4  5  6-434904290
7  8  9-434904266
90 80 70-434904026

What am I missing/doing wrong? Sorry if the code looks terrible. C++ is not my first native language

Comment: "_Create a integer type two-dimensional array of 4 rows and 3 columns_" - this I would draw on a paper before programming.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to init the value, just change this line to init it.

```cpp
int sum = 0;
```

Now the sum is a normal result.

In c++ the uninitialized integer will have garbage value if you don't init them.

You may reference this question:
[How garbage values are assigned to variables in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326611/how-garbage-values-are-assigned-to-variables-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum;
```

This declares a variable called `sum`, but ***does not initialize it to 0***. This is undefined behavior, manifesting itself as the initial value of sum being random garbage.

The subsequent loop adds a few more values to this random garbage, and then prints the random garbage as the result of the addition. So, simply initialize it to 0:

```
int sum=0;
```

By the way: all modern C++ compilers are very good in detecting this common programming mistake and issuing a warning, or a diagnostic message. If your compiler was completely silent, when compiling this program: this should indicate that you should update your compiler to something more modern. If your C++ compiler ***did*** issue a diagnostic message despite compiling your program, this is something to remember for the future: ***never*** ignore ***any*** advisory messages from your C++ compiler.

Comment: Thank you both! I don’t know how I didn’t catch that since I to the index but not the sum. I guess I wasn’t paying attention. 

@ Sam, I have a Macbook. When I ran it my compiler it didn’t give me an error or warning. What compiler would you recommend? I have Visual Studio Code installed but never got around to using it since the online one works well. The online one is onlinegdb

Comment: "Visual Studio" is not a C++ compiler. gcc 10, with `-Wall -Werror` compilation flags has no problems tell you that `error: ‘sum’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]`.

Comment: @FindMeTheArrayGuy To alleviate the confusion a bit: _Visual Studio Code_ is an editor. It can use whatever compiler you want.