# what is this "segmentation fault"

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int N,A[N],i;
    printf("Dizinin eleman sayisi : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    //int A[N];
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("Dizinin elemani : ");
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);

    }
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",A[i]);
    }
    
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("\ndizinin %d. elemani : %d\n", i,A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

I get this error when I want to save the array A to the beginning as N-dimensional.It's not a big deal, but I'm curious as I'm new to programming, thank you in advance.

Comment: Ask yourself: how big is `A` = what value is in `N` when `A` is declared?

Comment: In C programs are executed sequentially. Values read in a certain line are only available after that line was executed. The relevant line here is the one with first `scanf`

Comment: Re "*as N-dimensional*", It is one-dimensional. It has a number of elements equal to the value of `N` __at the time it was declared__. ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. It would have caught this. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: Make sure to accept the best answer below by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: I wrote a FAQ for this surprisingly common bug: [How to declare variable-length arrays correctly?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283440)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `N` is uninitialized when you define `int A[N]`.  This is undefined behavior.  Your program will probably segfault due to out of bound access of `A` which is also undefined behavior.   Arrays of size less than zero is undefined behavior but zero sized arrays are supported by some compilers as an extension. The array `int A[N]` is not resized when you later update `N`.

Always check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.

Prefer to minimize scope of variables (`i`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Dizinin eleman sayisi : ");
    int N;
    if(scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed or N <= 0\n");
            return 1;
    }
    int A[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Dizinin elemani : ");
        if(scanf("%d", &A[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf(" %d ", A[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        printf("\ndizinin %d. elemani : %d\n", i,A[i]);
}
```

and example output:

```
Dizinin eleman sayisi : 7
Dizinin elemani : 1
Dizinin elemani : 2
Dizinin elemani : 3
Dizinin elemani : 4
Dizinin elemani : 5
Dizinin elemani : 6
Dizinin elemani : 7
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
dizinin 0. elemani : 1

dizinin 1. elemani : 2

dizinin 2. elemani : 3

dizinin 3. elemani : 4

dizinin 4. elemani : 5

dizinin 5. elemani : 6

dizinin 6. elemani : 7
```

Comment: "Note that the array A is not resized when you later read N." I think this is the core of OPs minsunderstanding, a widely occurring one among new programmers. It deserves more prominent presentation. ... also I suspect it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Allan Wind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9706/allan-wind)'s answer,

In C, array declarations need a 'predefined' value. It's because they are not created when the execution comes to that row of the code, but they are declared exactly when the function's scope is created.

What it means is that when you code

```
int main() {
    int   size, arr[size];
    // some code
}
```

the variable 'size' and 'arr' will be declared when the program starts. 'size' will contain a [garbage value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326710/21242191), and the size of 'arr' will vary in each and every execution.

## Don't do it.

Although something like this is acceptable, I still wouldn't recommend using variable sized array declarations in general:

```
(any_type) function(unsigned (any_type) size)
{
   (any_type) arr[size];
   // some slightly better code
}
```

Note that 'unsigned' keyword prevents having a segfault -since we can't have a negative size-, it does not fix bad practice/implementation.

Comment: Note that `size=0` is still undefined behavior.